# Display entire output in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When using Powershell if I run a git command like `git branch -a` one page of information is displayed. When pressing enter an additional line is displayed. How can I print the rest of the information at one time, not line by line?

Comment: This is not really a Powershell issue or control. It's the git application. If you run git in any other shell, the same thing would occur. PowerShell allows other executable tools to be used in the console host, but it does not control it. So, see the git documentation.

Comment: @postanote Okay. I didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: no worries, there are always things that are new to us all, every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
[Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git):

```
-P
--no-pager

    Do not pipe Git output into a pager.
```